# InfluxQL: tag called Group causing grief

Tags: sql, influxdb

I have to work with an influxDB database and one of the tags is called Group. For example the query `select * from Testing limit 10` returns

```
time          Expiry     Group Parameter Type     value
----          ------     ----- --------- ----     -----
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Aleft     Combined -21.739
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Aright    Combined 0.933
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Bleft     Combined 43.097
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Bright    Combined 2.582
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Cleft     Combined 24.841
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Cright    Combined -3.444
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Dleft     Combined 12.012
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Dright    Combined 2.574
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Eleft     Combined 1.232
1623325196515 2021-06-18 GA011 Eright    Combined 15.764
```

The problem is when I try to have a rule based on group, e.g.

```
select * from Testing where Group='GA011'
```

I get an error that says

> ERR: error parsing query: found GROUP, expected identifier, string, number, bool at line 1, char 29.

Basically it treats `Group` as a function not as a tag. Is there any way to escape the keyword `Group` and query the database.

PS. I didn't have to do anything with the design and it cannot be changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can escape it  using double quote:

```
select * from Testing where "Group"='GA011'
```

Comment: Thanks! I failed to figure it out for hours... :/